# Key-Value-Observing closure never called on Boolean property

Tags: swift, cocoa, key-value-observing, nstoolbar

I have a class `ToolbarManager` that inherits from `NSObject`. It has a `toolbar` property defined as follows:

```
@objc dynamic let toolbar: NSToolbar
```

In the initializer of my class, I call the following code:

```
init(toolbar: NSToolbar) {
    self.toolbar = toolbar
    toolbar.allowsUserCustomization = true
    observation = observe(\.toolbar.customizationPaletteIsRunning, options: [.old, .new]) {
        (_, change) in
        print("was running: \(change.oldValue)")
        print("is running: \(change.newValue)")
    }
}
```

where `observation` is another property defined as follows:

```
var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

When I run the app and select *Customize Toolbar...* or close the customization view, the observation closure is never called, and thus nothing is printed to the console.

#### Why?

(And how can I fix that?)

---

#### Edit:

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift) states:

> You can only use key-value observing with classes that inherit from `NSObject`.

I'm not sure how to understand this. Does it mean that any property defined on `NSObject` subclasses can be observed or does it mean that only properties that are `NSObject` subclasses can be tracked?

(The latter would explain why my code doesn't work but then [this example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-key-value-observing) which observes a plain Swift string wouldn't work either. And it *does* work.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can only use key-value observing with classes that inherit from `NSObject`.

means it's required that only objects in a subclass of `NSObject` can be observed.

It does **not** mean that any object in a subclass of `NSObject` is implicitly observable.

It seems that this property of `NSToolbar` is not KVO compliant.

Comment: Is there any way to know if a property is KVO-compliant?

Comment: I don't know. The  `dynamic` attribute which makes the property observable does not appear in the Swift header even if the property is observable. But if the closure is not called it's not

Comment: Observable properties are usually documented as such. There's no way to determine that from the declaration.